# SQL Server : can't find the right 'join' formula for what I want

Tags: sql-server, join

I'm trying to find the right way to achieve this. Suppose I have 3 tables A, B and C.

I want my request to show some info from all 3 tables, but I want to show only one line by records that are in A.

The problem, if I join tables, is that there is most of the time a lot of B records linked to one A record, even worse, there is a lot of C linked to one B, so sometimes, the same A record is shown over a hundred times...

I tried `select top(1)` for B and `top(1)` again for C but still, it returns `top(1)` written on every 100 row of the same A, tried left join... inner join...

I'm trying to figure out how to group by but still can't find the right grouping. I ended up making A LOT of nested select, in fact, my query contains more nested select then anything else... it works but it takes forever...

1. Would it be faster if I find a way to remove most of my nested select ?
2. Is that even possible? I mean, did someone ever manage to accomplish this one line for all 'A' records query?

Comment: You can use EXISTS clause for that :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select * FROM A
OUTER APPLY (Select TOP 1 * FROM B Where A.colX = B.ColY) as New_B
OUTER APPLY (Select TOP 1 * FROM C Where A.colX = C.ColY) as New_C
```

You may need to modify the New_B and New_C Select statement to match your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use common table expression (cte) with `row_number`. Something like this.

```
;with cte as (
select a.id,b.name,c.price,
row_number() over(partition by a.id order by b.name, c.price) rn
from a inner join b on a.id = b.a_id
       inner join c on b.id = c.b_id
)
select * from cte
where rn=1
```